# Removing tabPanel(s) with same title in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

In base of [this](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.4/inserttab), what I want is

1. Allow multiple tabs with the same title
2. The button `remove` to remove the current selected tab

I tried the following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add", "Add Other tab"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove Current tab")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs"
                  ,tabPanel("Java", "tab for Java")
                  ,tabPanel("C++", "tab for C++")
                  ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python")
                  ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python")
                  
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Other language", "tab for other language"),
              select=TRUE
    )
  })
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = input$tabs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I selected the last "Python" tab and then click on the button `remove`, all the tabs with "Python" title are removed. I want only to remove the selected tab.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

The `removeTab()` [docs](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.4/inserttab) set out that the `target` parameter should be:

> the `value` of the tabPanel that you want to remove.

The default parameters for [`tabPanel()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.8.0/topics/tabPanel) are `tabPanel(title, ..., value = title, icon = NULL)`.

As you are creating two tabs with identical titles, `"Python"`, they have the same `value`, so `removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "Python")` will delete them both.

#### The solution

Simply create your Python tabs with different values:

```r
tabsetPanel(id = "tabs"
    ,tabPanel("Java", "tab for Java")
    ,tabPanel("C++", "tab for C++")
    ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python", value = "python1")
    ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python", value = "python2")
                  
)
```

As you can see below, when you click the <kbd>Remove current tab</kbd> button it now only deletes the selected tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to give a different `value` to those tabs:

```r
                  ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python", value = "python1")
                  ,tabPanel("Python", "tab for Python", value = "python2")
```